# Why use different approaches rather than direct, when connecting signals?

Tags: python, pyqt4

I am working with Python 3.3 and PyQt 4.10.1. Below figure is from [PyQt book](http://www.qtrac.eu/pyqtbook.html).

Assume that there are 5 buttons as shown below. When clicked on each, they will change label's text a context that includes their button number. For example, when user clicks on the button with caption "Four" on it, it will change the label to `You clicked button 'Four'`

[image]

Instead of creating a signal slot for each of the buttons, a generalised method is created which accepts a paramater and `partial()` method is used:

```
    ...
    self.label = QLabel("Click on a button.")
    self.button1 = QPushButton("One")
    ...
    self.button5 = QPushButton("Five")
    self.connect(self.button1, SIGNAL("clicked()")
                                , partial(self.anyButton, "One"))
    ...
    self.connect(self.button5, SIGNAL("clicked()")
                                , partial(self.anyButton, "Five"))
    ...

def anyButton(self, buttonNumber):
    self.label.setText("You clicked button '%s'" % buttonNumber)
```

Whenever I want to change `partial(self.anyButton, "One")` to `self.anyButton("One")`, I get an error like below.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\abdullah\Desktop\test.py", line 47, in <module>
    form = Form()
  File "C:\Users\abdullah\Desktop\test.py", line 20, in __init__
    , self.anyButton("One"))
TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:
  QObject.connect(QObject, SIGNAL(), QObject, SLOT(), Qt.ConnectionType=Qt.AutoC
onnection): argument 3 has unexpected type 'NoneType'
  QObject.connect(QObject, SIGNAL(), callable, Qt.ConnectionType=Qt.AutoConnecti
on): argument 3 has unexpected type 'NoneType'
  QObject.connect(QObject, SIGNAL(), SLOT(), Qt.ConnectionType=Qt.AutoConnection
): argument 3 has unexpected type 'NoneType'
```

What is the reason for this? Why I cannot directly call the function? Also, why `partial()` method works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`partial` returns you the *function* `anyButton` where the argument is substituted.

`self.anyButton("One")` gives you the *value* returned by the function.

Comment: +1 and the `connect` requires a callback **function** not a value.

Comment: BTW, this function does not return any value :)